# Spymemcached : How to get information about a cached data?

Tags: memcached, hazelcast, infinispan, spymemcached

I use **Spymemcached** to get instances from a cache server.

How can I know information such as the date of **creation/modification of an instance**?

**Additional Info :**

I'm testing over two servers **Infinispan** and **Hazelcast**.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible through Memcached protocol - see the [protocol specification](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt). When such information is not provided through the protocol, you cannot find any method in the API.

The only possibility is to store create/modify time as part of the value or in the 32 bit flags (these are opaque to the server).

Comment: Spymemcached uses the flags for serialization so you should not try to store any user data in that field.